# SSL handshake yields BIO errors

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl

Fairly new to socket programming, but I've been assigned with a whopper of project.

My issue is this:  I try initiating an SSL handshake with both SSL_accept() and SSL_connect(), as well as renegotiating the handshake and then attempting to reconnect with SSL_renegotiate() and SSL_do_handshake() in succession, but all of these give me the error of BIO routines:BIO_write:unsupported method

Before making any calls, I make sure to set my BIO and initialize all SSL libraries.

The BIO and SSL pointers are *not* null during the time of execution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Posting some of your 'init' code for both the client and server side would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to tell without seeing any code but the error 'unsupported method' means that you are problably trying to call a function with the wrong BIO as parameter. In other words, you cannot call BIO_write with an accept BIO (one created with, eg, a call to BIO_new_accept()). An accept BIO is for, well, accepting connections.

Comment: Ah, so the BIO itself needs to be created specifically for the server or the client, then attached to the SSL before the transaction?  Makes sense.  I'll update with more information once I try this.  Thanks in advance!